# How to dynamically add lists to a list, then add items to that newly added list in the list of lists?

Tags: c#, list, while-loop, nested-lists

Say I have a list of fruits organised in a list. The list is organized so that firstly the word 'person' will appear on the list and all proceeding items after that person are fruit that belong in their basket. Then the next person listed marks a parse moment to start a new list of fruits for a new person. Finally I want all these lists of fruits for all these people to be compiled into a list of lists. The number of fruits and number of people are unknown. However the types of fruits that can appear are known.

Here's an example list if the above doesn't make sense:

```
Person
Apple
Apple
Cherry
Apple
Orange
Person
Grape
Lemon
Apple
Apple
```

Only available fruits: Apple, Cherry, Orange, Grape, Lemon

Here's my attempt at the code, I used comments where I think list adding should occur but I'm not sure what the syntax should be (thats what I'm asking for help with):

```
while (notAtEndOfList)
{
    //create a new list of fruit for a person
    while (notAtEndOfList && input != "person")
    {
        nameOfDynamicallyCreatedFruitList.add(input.ToString());
    }
    peopleWithFruitList.add(nameOfDynamicallyCreatedFruitList);
}
```

Comment: You know you could, for example, have a `Dictionary<String, List<String> >`, but not easy to see what you're ultimately trying to achieve. Using one list to store items for multiple people doesn't sound like a good idea.

Comment: oh c# has dictionaries?? awesome thanks

Comment: There are many possible data structures which may help you. For example you can create a `Person` class containing a `string Name` and a `List<Fruit> Fruits`. Then you can have a `List<Person>` to keep those people and their fruits.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Thats actually pretty clever, but the dictionary idea looks cool since I've never done one in c# before. Is it possible to make a dictionary of lists? I suppose not. Actually I'll probably just put the list in my class. Thanks for the idea again. :)

Comment: If you want to go with dictionary, the `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` which is mentioned by @LeeTaylor is exactly what you need. The keys are people and the value for each key is a `List<string>` which is fruits.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Why don't you submit your answers as answers? Aren't comments usually only about clarifications? If you submit that as an answer I can mark it for future people who stumble upon this problem

Comment: @CapnJack - Done. I can expand if you need more advice.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I'm actually using the idea of putting a list inside of a class. and then making a list of that class type. It just fits what I'm doing in a more organized fashion. In my class I have two variables, the list and a string called name. If I want to edit that string value I can access it by peopleList[0].name however when I try to access the fruit list inside the class I get an error. peopleList[0].fruitList.add() doesn't seem to work. Do you know the syntax for accessing a list inside of a class? thanks! (Lee Taylor feel free to answer too, I can only @ 1 person)

Comment: Woops nevermind... forgot to make the list in the class public smh

Comment: Both properties `Name` and `Fruits` should be public. (As you also discovered yourself;) )

Comment: @RezaAghaei never really got the point of keeping things private? It's the default control type in a lot of cases. The only explanation I can come up with is it lets you reuse the same variable names in different forms and classes but there has to be a greater purpose than that right? Maybe it's better I ask "why not just make all variables public to being with? Why bother making then private?"

Comment: *Usually* for a data structure like what I proposed, all properties are public. That's why the C# allows you to define properties this way `public string Name { get; set; }` and get rid of private member variables. But you may want to have something private in your class. For example IMO, the setter of the `Fruits` is better to be private this way: `public List<Fruit> Fruits { get; private set; }`, then you can instantiate the list in constructor of `Person` class yourself `Fruits = new List<Fruit>();` and don't let making the `Fruits`  null from outside of your class.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Also even though my list is public I can't access it in a separate form. I'm making a pop up window form that displays each person and their fruits in their baskets. So I need to be able to see the contents of this list. Even read only would work if writing to the list cross forms is too difficult.

Comment: If you created the person class containing fruits, to show a person and its fruits in another form, you need to pass `Person` class to that form. You don't need to make `People` list public. Just pass the person which you want to show to the other form. The linked post which was about 
*Interaction between forms — How to change a control of a form from another form?* Also contains such example. The first example is about passing data to constructor of the second form which you want to show data.

Comment: I'm really confused with what you mean by "Just pass the person which you want to show to the other form". My understanding of this is that where the form is declared with the initialization there are brackets. So in the brackets I could write "listViewer(person randomNameForPassedPerson)"and then in my new form 'listViewer' I would be able to access that passed person with the variable name 'randomNameForPassedPerson'. Much like a function? If that's how I receive a parameter, how do I send one from my main form? Do I put the variable in the listViewer.ShowDialogue() brackets?

Comment: Don't avoid from reading the first example of that link *Example1 - Using constructor of second Form*. You need to have a constructor in your second form that accepts a `Person`. `public SecondForm(Person p)`. Then in your first form, when you want to show a person using an instance of second form, you can do it this way: `var f = new SecondForm(people[0]); f.ShowDialog();` The example which I showed to you, did the job using an int variable, you need to do it using `Person` type. By the way, mention me when you post a comment for me, otherwise I wont be notified and will miss your comment :)

Comment: @RezaAghaei woops my bad. I'm very close now that post helped a lot. but I'm struggling with saving the parameter passed into the new form. When I call this type of line: "var f = new SecondForm(people[0]);" I successfully see the value passed to the new form. but that value stays inside the scope of the constructor. How do I pass it out of that scope and have it readily available for when I call showDialogue()?

Comment: You can have a *private* member variable in scope of form and assign the value which you have in constructor to that member, then you can use it somewhere else like `Load` event of form. For example create a `private Person myPerson;` in `SecondForm` and then in constructor, `public  SecondForm(Person p){ myPerson = p; }` Then you can use `myPerson` wherever you need in your second form.

Comment: @RezaAghaei So sorry but this still isn't making sense to me. To simplify lets call the main form (the one with the list in it) form1, and the pop-up form we'll call form2. How do I keep the value passed from form1 into form2 after initializing it?

Comment: This simple: `public class Form2 { Person myPerson; public Form2(Person p) { InitializeComponent(); myPerson = p;}}` and when you want to show `Form2`, you can `var f = new Form2(people[0]); f.ShowDialog();`. Just read example 1 carefully :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the following data structure to represent your data:

```
Dictionary<String, List<String>> MyData = new Dictionary<String, List<String>>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
  static class Program
  {
    static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>> SliceBy(this IEnumerable<string> data, string delimiter)
    {
      string key = null;
      List<string> values = null;

      foreach (var item in data)
      {
        if (item == delimiter)
        {
          if (key != null)
          {
            yield return new KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>(key, values);
          }
          key = item;
          values = new List<string>();
        }
        else
        {
          values.Add(item);
        }
      }

      if (key != null)
        yield return new KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>(key, values);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var personFruits = new[] { "Person", "Apple", "Apple", "Cherry", "Apple", "Orange", "Person", "Grape", "Lemon", "Apple", "Apple", "Person", "Grape", "Lemon", "Apple", "Apple" };
      var result = personFruits.SliceBy("Person");

      foreach (var person in result)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(person.Key);
        foreach (var fruit in person.Value)
        {
          Console.WriteLine(fruit);
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
      }

    }
  }
```